# What is the main carrier in a semiconductor with n-type material being electrons and p-type materials being holes?

Tags: theory, homework, materials, reference-materials

Not even gonna lie this is for a crossword. it is a 15 letter word. I have searched online, in my textbooks and I cannot figure out what it is. Closest I've found is [Extrinsic Semiconductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrinsic_semiconductor) but it's too big for the box.

Anyone know what it is or care to point me in the right direction?

Comment: majoritycarrier

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has nothing to do with electronic design, it is about a crossword puzzle

Answer (score 1):

It's gotta be majority carrier.

Comment: This does not answer the question, it is a comment

Comment: But it does answer the question.

Comment: @laptop2d He asked a solution for the crossword puzzle and not an explanation for **Why are holes majority carriers in p-type or e- in n-type?**. So, my answer does answer his question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the question was on-topic, I'll get it closed

Answer (score 0):

N-type material makes no sense at all. Actually N-type is a extrinsic semiconductor type. 
Extrinsic semiconductor is any semiconductor doped with impurity. Impurity is an atom with 3 or 5 valence electon.
And intrinsic semiconductor has no impurity in it. Eg... a pure silicon
Semiconductors are made of elements with 4 valence electrons. When atoms with 3 valence electrons are injected in the silicon material,all electron of silicon forms bond  with the electons of added inpurity. But one electon of silicon cant form this bond as there are only three available electrons. There is space with shortage of electon.This empty space is called hole  which is not the actual+ve charge but only the lack of -ve charge. So when few atoms with 3 valence electrons are injected, the holes get formed. So these types of semiconductors are called p-type since they have positive charge carriers (which are relatively+ve in comparison to electrons)
The N-type semiconductor has electron as charge carrier. This is due to the injection of atoms with 5 valence electrons. During the formation of bond, one electron is excess. This excess charge carrier carries -ve charge. So this type of semiconductor is called n-type semiconductor.

So regarding charge carrier, it is hole for p-type and electon for n-type.
Hope it helped you.